# window.onscroll no longer works when implementing parallax with body tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble getting the `onscroll`  event when I try to implement a parallax effect using the `body` tag. See my code below.

When I comment out the sections in the CSS corresponding to `html`, `parallax`, `parallax-front` and `parallax-back` (i.e. all the CSS that makes the parallax work), the `onscroll` event works fine. As soon as I uncomment them, it stops working. I have also tried `document.onscroll`, `document.body.onscroll` and these do not work either.

Why is it not working and how can I get the `onscroll` event to work?

```js
function log(msg) {
  console.log(new Date() + ": " + msg);
}

window.onload = function() {
  log("loaded");
};

window.onscroll = function() {
  log(document.body.scrollTop);
};
```

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax {
  margin: 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  perspective: 1px;
  perspective-origin: 0 0;

  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parallax-front {
  transform: translateZ(0px);
}

.parallax-back {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}

#banner {
  height: 10rem;
  line-height: 10rem;
  background: pink;
  border: 8px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  height: 50rem;
  background: rgba(224, 224, 255, 0.9);
  border: 8px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <body class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax-back">
      <div id="banner">Banner</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax-front">
      <div id="content">Content</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you shouldn't be able to scroll anywhere when you have `overflow: hidden` applied to `html`.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? You don't see my example work?